# How to scale all key frames in a layer of grease pencil?

Tags: transforms, keyframes, grease-pencil

While animating in grease pencil Blender,
I need to scale all key frames in a layer at a time.

I cant find any option to do so.
Is it possible in grease pencil to enlarge all key frames with same percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you parent your grease pencil to an object - in this example an empty - the children will follow the scale that mum or dad tells them to do...

[image: Grease Pencil parent]